Definition of first order differential operator
I found this definition of first order differential operator in the book Global Calculus by S. Ramanan, which I can't understand.

A homogeneous first order differential operator on a differential manifold $M$ is a linear operator on $\mathcal{A}(M)$ satisfying the Leibniz rule. Equivalently, it is a sheaf homomorphism $\mathcal{A\to A}$ which satisfies the Leibniz rule.

I don't understand how a map $\mathcal{A}(M)\to\mathcal{A}(M)$ can induce a sheaf homomorphism $\mathcal{A}\to\mathcal{A}$. It seems to me that it is false, as in general there are many functions that are not the restriction of a global function.
But maybe in this specific matter we can do something like partition of unity?

The coefficients of a differential operator must be defined globally. The functions it acts on need not be.

There is a proposition hidden in the statement. If you have a linear operator $D$ on $\mathcal A(M)$ that satisfies a Leibniz rule then it automatically is a local operator, i.e. $D(f)|_U$ depends only on $f|_U$. Once you have that, you can indeed use partitions of unity to obtain a sheaf homomorphism.
To prove this proposition, it suffices to show that $f|_U=0$ implies $D(f)|_U=0$. To do this, you take $x\in U$ and a bump function $\phi$ with support contained in $U$ such that $\phi(x)=1$. Then $\phi f$ by construction and hence $0=D(\phi f)=D(\phi)f+\phi D(f)$. Evaluating in $x$ the first summand vanishes since $f(x)=0$ and you get $0=\phi(x)D(f)(x)= D(f)(x)$. Since $x$ is arbitrary, this proves the claim.

Thank you for the answer. I tried to complete the proof. The locality of $D$ and partition of unity induce a map $D:E(\mathcal{A})\to E(\mathcal{A})$ between the stalks. It remains to prove the continuity of this map. By passing to a chart, $D$ can be written as a linear combination of partial derivations with coefficients $D(x^i)_x$, which are differentiable by partition of unity on a compact subset. So finally $D$ is a sheaf homomorphism on some open set, completing the proof. This is so complicated...

Usually, there is no need to pass to stalks and/or to think about continuity. To have a morphism of sheafs it should be sufficient to show that for each open $U$ one has $D=D_U:\mathcal A(U)\to\mathcal A(U)$ and that this is compatible with restrictions. Both properties are essentially obvious from the construction.

Yes, that argument can be avoided. But the construction of $D_U$ is still not so obvious to me. I can't find a way to directly handle $\mathcal{A}(U)$. It seems that taking a coordinate chart to pass to $\mathbb{R}^n$ and using its property to deduce $D=\sum(Dx_i)\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$ is an essential step.

There is no need to do all that: Given $f\in \mathcal A(U)$ you directly define $D_U(f)$: Given $x\in U$, there is $V\subset U$ open with $x\in V$ and $\tilde f\in\mathcal A(M)$ such that $\tilde f|_V=f|_V$ and one puts $D_U(f)(x):=D(\tilde f)(x)$. The upshot of my reply is that this is well defined and then by construction $D_U(f)|_V=D(\tilde f)|_V$, which shows that $D_U(f)$ is smooth a neighborhood of $x$ and since $x$ is arbitrary, this shows that $D_U(f)\in\mathcal A(U)$.
